# Correct place to define reusable functions in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have lots of functions, lets say P(), Q(), R(), S(), T() and I have 3 controllers, A, B and C.

Controller A uses P() and Q(), B uses R(), S() and T() while C uses P(), Q() and T().

I have already defined the controllers, where should I define functions (which folder)? how do I include them in the controllers?

The functions maybe used in some other controllers later (and they can be categorized).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put them in the services folder. Here is what [the docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/api/services) stipulates:

> 'Services' are similar to controller actions but are typically used for things that don't nessecarily have to happen between the time when the user sends a request and when the server sends back a response. Any logic that doesn't rely on .req() and .res() can be turned into a service if for no other reason than to keep your controllers clean and managable.

For example, you can create a `Utils` service:

```
// api/services/Utils.js

module.exports.p = function (a, b, c) {
  // Do whatever...
};

module.exports.q = function (a, b, c) {
  // Do whatever...
  return c();
};

// And so on
```

And use these functions in your controllers like this:

```
// api/controllers/A.js

module.exports = {

  anAction: function (req, res) {
    // ...
    Utils.p('hello', 1, [123, 456]);
    Utils.q('world', 0, function () {
      // ...
    });
    // ...
  }

};
```

You can also access the service functions with `sails.services['utils'].theFunctionName()` and replace `theFunctionName` by the name of the function you want to use (e.g. `p`).

Answer (score 7):

In Sails 1.0 you should use [Helpers](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers) instead of Services.

> As of v1.0, all Sails apps come with built-in support for helpers,
>   simple utilities that let you share Node.js code in more than one
>   place. This helps you avoid repeating yourself, and makes development
>   more efficient by reducing bugs and minimizing rewrites. Like
>   actions2, this also makes it much easier to create documentation for
>   your app.

You can generate a new helper running the command:

> sails generate helper get-current-date

A new file will be created under the `helpers` folder. Example:

```
module.exports = {
    friendlyName: 'Get current date',
    description: 'Creates a new Date object and returns it',
    inputs: {},
    exits: {
        success: {
            outputFriendlyName: 'Current date',
            outputType: 'ref'
        },
    },
    fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
        return exits.success(new Date());
    }
};
```

Then just use it like `sails.helpers.getCurrentDate()`.

Comment: I also want to add that helpers have the option of using .with() when you call them. This allows the inputs to be passed in as an object, rather than as a list of parameters. For example, if I have a helper called `update-user-password` that takes 'userId' and 'newPassword' as inputs, i can call the helper like: `sails.helpers.updateUserPassword.with({userId: ... , newPassword: ...})`. It may not make a lot of sense to do that in this simple example, but when your helpers have a lot of inputs it can be much easier to read/use.